# Bottle neck on SORT operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016

I have the following query and it's proving very costly and is taking 6-8 seconds to execute. Looking at the execution plan, the cost is 79% on a SORT operation. Can I get any improvement here?

[image: IMG]

```
    SELECT
        A.StageName,
        C.Month,
        C.MonthName as Label,
        C.Year,
        isnull(A.Average,0) as Data
    FROM
    (   
        SELECT 
            S.StageName,
            MONTH(TimeIn) as MonthNumber, 
            DATENAME(MONTH,TimeIn) as Month, 
            YEAR(TimeIn) as Year, 
            ISNULL(AVG(DATEDIFF(mi,TimeIn,isnull(TimeOut,@TodayDate))),0) as Average
        FROM
            VisitMovement VM
        INNER JOIN Stage S on
            VM.StageID = S.StageID
        WHERE 
            (VM.TimeIn >= @StartDate AND 
            VM.TimeIn  < DATEADD (d,1,@EndDate)) AND
            (VM.TimeOut < DATEADD (d,1,@EndDate) OR VM.TimeOut IS NULL)
        GROUP BY
            S.StageNumber,
            S.StageName,
            MONTH(TimeIn), 
            DATENAME(MONTH,TimeIn), 
            YEAR(TimeIn)
    ) A
    RIGHT JOIN (select distinct Month,MonthName,Year from Calendar WHERE DATE >= @StartDate AND DATE < DATEADD (d,1,@EndDate)) C on
        A.MonthNumber = C.Month and
        A.Month = C.MonthName and
        A.Year = C.Year 
    GROUP BY
        A.StageName,
        C.Month,
        C.MonthName,
        C.Year,
        A.Average   
    ORDER BY  
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc'  THEN C.Year            END ASC, 
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc'  THEN C.Month           END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc'  THEN A.StageName       END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc' THEN C.Year            END DESC, 
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc' THEN C.Month           END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc'  THEN A.StageName      END DESC
```

Comment: The most expensive sort in your plan is happening because of the `Stream Aggregate` iterator as this iterator expects sorted inputs, and the `Stream Aggregate` iterator is there because of your `inner group by` clause. Try to get the unique rows without using the `Group by` clause, that will drop the `Stream Aggregate` and the sort will disappear too.

Comment: Thanks @M.Ali - that's impossible unfortunately as I need to group all the records in the table in order to calculate the overall average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I understand you can't get rid of the `GROUP BY` on the different columns in the sub-query, you can make it easier for the system.

Currently you have

```
S.StageNumber,
S.StageName,
MONTH(TimeIn), 
DATENAME(MONTH,TimeIn), 
YEAR(TimeIn)
```

Which I guess is quite a lot of data to go through. Allow me to make some guesses:

```
S.StageNumber,  -- int, 4 bytes
S.StageName, -- string, 20 bytes
MONTH(TimeIn),  -- int, 4 bytes
DATENAME(MONTH,TimeIn),  -- string 5 bytes
YEAR(TimeIn) -- int, 4 byte
```

Now, there are some dependencies:

- If you know the MONTH (number), then you also now the name of it
- I'm guessing that StageName + StageNumber is unique and directly related to StageID. If not you may have to GROUP BY once more in the outer layer.

That would bring us to

```
S.StageID,  -- int, 4 bytes
MONTH(TimeIn),  -- int, 4 bytes
YEAR(TimeIn) -- int, 4 byte
```

This means that the sorting for the `GROUP BY` has to run through only 12 bytes per record instead of the 37 bytes per record it was before, and numbers sort quite a bit faster than strings anyway (e.g. due to upper/lower case, accents, etc..)

I've tried to rewrite the query accordingly (Untested!). I've also moved the fetch of Month-information to a separate temp-table, this should help the Query Optimizer a little bit.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Month,MonthName,Year 
  INTO #dates
  FROM Calendar 
 WHERE DATE >= @StartDate AND DATE < DATEADD (d,1,@EndDate)

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX uq0_#dates ON #dates (Month,Year)

SELECT
        A.StageName,
        C.Month,
        C.MonthName as Label,
        C.Year,
        isnull(A.Average,0) as Data
    FROM 
    (   
        SELECT S.StageName,
               MonthNumber,
               Year,
               Average
          FROM (    
                  SELECT VM.StageID,
                         MONTH(TimeIn) as MonthNumber, 
                         YEAR(TimeIn) as Year, 
                         ISNULL(AVG(DATEDIFF(mi,TimeIn,isnull(TimeOut,@TodayDate))),0) as Average
                    FROM
                         VisitMovement VM
                   WHERE 
                        (VM.TimeIn >= @StartDate AND 
                        VM.TimeIn  < DATEADD (d,1,@EndDate)) AND
                        (VM.TimeOut < DATEADD (d,1,@EndDate) OR VM.TimeOut IS NULL)
                  GROUP BY
                        VM.StageID,
                        MONTH(TimeIn), 
                        YEAR(TimeIn)
               ) grp
          JOIN Stage S 
            ON S.StageID = grp.StageID
        )
    ) A
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN #dates C
    on
        A.MonthNumber = C.Month and
        -- A.Month = C.MonthName and
        A.Year = C.Year 
    ORDER BY  
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc'  THEN C.Year            END ASC, 
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc'  THEN C.Month           END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'asc'  THEN A.StageName       END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc' THEN C.Year            END DESC, 
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc' THEN C.Month           END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @Ordering = 'desc'  THEN A.StageName      END DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many apologies for the delayed response @deroby. I was away over the Xmas/New Year period. Thanks for your solution and Happy New Year :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the `order by` has to evaluate each row, I don't think it can make optimal use of indices. Replacing the `order by` with a `row_number()` for the default sorting and only reversing the order once should at the least prevent multiple evaluations of `@Ordering` for a single row.

In the pseudo code below, the original query is put in a CTE. Row_number determines the ascending sort and below the cte the order is reversed if needed:

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT
        A.StageName,
        C.Month,
        ...,
        row_number() over (order by C.Year,C.Month,A.StageName) sortOrder
    FROM
       ...rest of the query, excluding the order by
)
select * --or list the columns without the sortOrder 
from cte
order by sortOrder * case @Ordering when 'desc' then -1 else 1 end
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Me.Name - appreciate the advice. Using the cte approach however makes the query even slower unfortunately. With the CTE approach, it also puts a yellow explanation mark over the top of the Sort operation.